# What is the difference between nfs_readpage and nfs_read?

Tags: nfs, virtual-memory, read, iostat

Does every `nfs_read` always has a `nfs_readpage` request or does both are exclusive? Please explain.

I am trying to understand this: http://www.fsl.cs.stonybrook.edu/~mchen/mountstat-format.txt

Comment: The file you link to doesn't mention either `nfs_read` or `nfs_readpage`; could you expand your question a little? *E.g.* explain what led you to `nfs_read`, `nfs_readpage`...

Comment: @StephenKitt Hi, thanks for asking. I read it here: https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/linux/nfs_iostat.h see the definition of: fs_stat_bytecounters and I have understood all variables except that NFSIOS_READPAGES and NFSIOS_WRITEPAGES